# Preparing concrete slab for porcelain tile after removing vinyl tiles and mastic

Tags: flooring, tile, adhesive, slab, preparation

My bathroom has VAT (vinyl asbestos tile) and I have taken to removing it by steaming the tiles and peeling them up slowly. For the black mastic underneath I am using BlueBear 500MR which is just a soybean oil that emulsifies the mastic. The mastic is then squeegeed away into an absorbent compound from ZEP. Relatively painless so far and has worked quite well. BlueBear Recommends a degreaser (BlueBear 700DG) afer use to remove the remaining oil.

This is where things become unclear for me. I have read that the degreaser will remove the "sealer" from the slab and render new adhesive unbondable. Once I clean the floor of the mastic and mastic remover with degreaser, how should I proceed to prep the surface of the slab for adhesion? Do I need to prime/reseal the concrete?

Home built in southern U.S. in 1970s. I have ordered the degreaser product and am waiting on it. So far this has been done in a test spot but I want clarity before I proceed..